# PHP Form Error even without attached File

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that users may choose to upload a file to and it will send an email with the file as an attachment.

The issue I am having is that AJAX alert below always gives me the `The uploaded file is not a supported file type.` message from the PHP code even if I did not choose any files to attach.

```
if (data.error) {
   alert(data.error.message);
 }`
```

AJAX Code:

```
$(document).ready(function (e){
$("#main-contact-form").on('submit',(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#sendingemail').fadeIn();
        $.ajax({
        url: "../sendemail.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            if (data.error) {
                    alert(data.error.message);
                }
            else{
                $('#sendingemail').fadeOut();
                $('#emailsent').fadeIn();
              alert(data.message);
            }
        },
      error: function(XHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
              console.log(data);
            //alert("error");
              alert(XHR.status);
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    }           
 );
}));
});
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

    header('Content-type: application/json');

            // WE SHOULD ASSUME THAT THE EMAIL WAS NOT SENT AT FIRST UNTIL WE KNOW MORE.
            // WE ALSO ADD AN ATTACHMENT KEY TO OUR STATUS ARRAY TO INDICATE THE STATUS OF OUR ATTACHMENT:  
            $status = array(
                            'type'          =>'Error',
                            'message'       =>'Couldn\'t send the Email at this Time. Something went wrong',
                            'attachement'   =>'Couldn\'t attach the uploaded File to the Email.'
            );

    //Added to deal with Files
    require_once('PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

    if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])){    
    //Get the uploaded file information
        $name_of_uploaded_file =
            basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

        //get the file extension of the file
        $type_of_uploaded_file =
            substr($name_of_uploaded_file,
            strrpos($name_of_uploaded_file, '.') + 1);

        $size_of_uploaded_file =
            $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"]/1024;//size in KBs

        //Settings
        $max_allowed_file_size = 10000; // size in KB
        $allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp","png");

        //Validations
        if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_allowed_file_size )
        {
          $status['type']    = 'Error';
        $status['message'] = 'Error: Size of file should be less than ~10MB. The file you attempted to upload is too large. To reduce the size, open the file in an image editor and change the Image Size and resave the file.';
          echo(json_encode($status));
          exit;
        }

        //------ Validate the file extension -----
        $allowed_ext = false;
        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($allowed_extensions); $i++)
        {
          if(strcasecmp($allowed_extensions[$i],$type_of_uploaded_file) == 0)
          {
                $allowed_ext = true;
          }
        }

        if(!$allowed_ext)
        {
          $status['type']    = 'Error';
        $status['message'] = 'Error: The uploaded file is not a supported file type.';
          echo(json_encode($status));
            exit;
        }

  $upload_folder = "temp/";
        $path_of_uploaded_file = $upload_folder . $name_of_uploaded_file;
        $tmp_path = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"];

        if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_path))
        {
          if(!copy($tmp_path,$path_of_uploaded_file))
          {
              $status['type']    = 'Error';
            $status['message']   = 'Error: Encountered an error while copying the uploaded file';
            exit;
          }
        }
}
    //--end

    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
    $clientemail = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
    $subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $clientemail . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

     $email = new PHPMailer();      

    $email->From      = $clientemail;
    $email->FromName  = $name;
    $email->Subject   = $subject;
    $email->Body      = $body;  
    $email->AddAddress( 'root@localhost.com' ); //Send to this email

    $email->isMail();

  if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])){   
                if($email->AddAttachment( $path_of_uploaded_file , $name_of_uploaded_file )){
            $status['message']   = 'The Uploaded File was successfully attached to the Email.';  
        }
  }
        header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);
 // NOW, TRY TO SEND THE EMAIL ANYWAY:
        try{
            $success    = $email->send();
            $status['type']    = 'success';
            $status['message']  = 'Thank you for contacting us. We will reply as soon as possible.';   
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $status['type']     ='Error';
            $status['message']  ='Couldn\'t send the Email at this Time. Something went wrong';     
        }   

 die(json_encode($status));
```

HTML:

```
        <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email *</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Phone</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Company Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>                        
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Subject *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Message *</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" style="height:125px"></textarea>
                    <label for='uploaded_file' style="margin-top:10px">Select A Photo To Upload:</label>
                    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
                </div>                        
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Submit Message</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: can i know what type of file you upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find when you `print_r($_FILES)`, even when you have not attached a file, will give you this array:

```
Array
(
    [uploaded_file] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )
)
```

You do not want to check `isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])` but rather if

1. `$_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0` or
2. `!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'])`

   ---

EDIT:

Just so I am clear, my answer is addressing the comment that you receive your error message *"...even if I did not choose any files to attach"*. My answer explains why this would occur.

Comment: Badrush is restricting file format. No Error in that code.

Comment: @Raj_King The OP says they are getting their error `'Error: The uploaded file is not a supported file type.'` when no file is attached. They of course will get this error because when they submit the form, they are only checking that the `$_FILES` array is set, not that there was anything attached. By default it is set (aka always going to be `true`), so the extension does not exist, therefore it will always say that when no file is attached.

Comment: He is validating file extension. if extension mismatch with his restricted formats, he throws an error that `'Error: The uploaded file is not a supported file type.'`
That is the custom error message thrown by the following code.
`if (!$allowed_ext) {
        $status['type'] = 'Error';
        $status['message'] = 'Error: The uploaded file is not a supported file type.';
        echo(json_encode($status));
        exit ;
    `
Other than that this code working with `jpg jpeg gif bmp png` formats

Comment: @Raj_King I am not debating the that the OP may be restricting the format, but the OP clearly states that their custom error is thrown when a file is NOT attached, which of course it would because if the user does not attach anything then there is no extension to check against and the OP is only checking if the `$_FILES` array is set. By default the `$_FILES` is set in the form, ergo they will get that error because it's not checking that something is actually attached.

Comment: @Raj_King if the OP checked that one of the elements was `!empty` like the `name` field OR that there was no error `error=>0`, meaning something was actually attached, then it would go into that portion of the code. If a file is not attached, it should not get past the first `if` condition.

Comment: I Agree with you. here if `$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']` is `Empty` it throws `Undefined variable: name_of_uploaded_file` but it did not. so the file is attached and format is the issue here. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @Raj_King Which part are you talking about? This: `$name_of_uploaded_file = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);` If so, that would not throw `undefined` error because `$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']` is set even if there IS or IS NOT a file attached. If no file is attached, the key is still set, the value would be empty is all and you can `basename()` an empty value without getting an error.

Comment: @Raj_King I think we can agree to disagree without the OP providing a more comprehensive scenario where this error is occurring. I understand what you are saying, and it is valid if the user has attached a file type that is not in the approved list of extensions, but your explanation does not directly explain why they would receive the error when they have not attached a file at all.

Comment: @Raj_King ... to clear things up Rasclatt was correct. I said in my post "The issue I am having is that AJAX alert below always gives me the The uploaded file is not a supported file type. message from the PHP code even if I did not choose any files to attach." which clearly shows that I was having an issue sending emails without attachments.

Comment: Thanks Rascall, first of all your reading comprehension is very good. Second of all I used `!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'])` because it is more clear what it is looking for and it worked. Now I can send files with or without attachments.